# Vim leader key mapping for zR?

Tags: vim

I've created many leader key mappings in my .vimrc file for commands that you enter after typing ":".  For example,

```
map <Leader>sw :StripWhitespace<CR>
```

But how do you create a leader key mapping in .vimrc for a command that you like "zR" which opens all folds? This isn't a command that you would type ":" before entering it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create it in much the same way: leader combination, followed by the key combination you want it to map to. There's nothing particularly special about the ex command mappings. So for example, I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>^</kbd> mapped to <kbd>leader</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>:

```
map <Leader>p <C-^>
```

because it's a particularly annoying combination to reach on my split keyboard. In your case, I imagine you'd use:

```
map <Leader>ff zR
```

Obviously, <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> is just an example binding. You don't need a `<CR>` because you don't need one when typing the command in normal mode either.